# How to make a mesh chair surface using a good toplogy

Tags: modeling, modifiers, topology, subdivision-surface, dynamic-topology

I'm making a modeling similar to a mesh chair. I don't think my way of modeling is good for topology, so I'd like to hear about your experience.

The way I used to use it is the same as the third picture. This is a method that uses the Union effect of the Boolean modifier and then implements surface boundaries and details with sculpting.

How do you make this model easier? Is there a good way?

For the implementation of mesh and frame surface.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

My toplogy:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). We can't see your topology here, please consider adding a wireframe with side views. You can also [upload your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: @JachymMichal Hello:) I updated my toplogy. Please check it.